# Distance between buildings

Tags: osmnx

I want to calculate the distances between buildings. First I get graph_from_place, after I get geometries_from_place. For all geometries I eather take the point or the polygon.centroid as center. To the center I want to get_nearest_node. Unfortunately, all nearest nodes are far away and the same node. What am I doing wrong or how can I calculate the distance between buildings? I tried some different smaller towns and it always leads to the same problem. Thank you very much!

```
import osmnx as ox
from IPython.display import IFrame
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
ox.\__version__

place = "Neuenburg am Rhein, Landkreis Breisgau-Hochschwarzwald, Baden-Württemberg, 79395, Germany"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place)

tags = {'building': True, 'amenity': True, 'addr:housenumber': True}
buildings = ox.geometries_from_place(place, tags)

buildings['center'] = buildings['geometry']

count_buildings_point = 0
count_buildings_poly = 0

for i in range(len(buildings)):
    if(buildings.loc[i, 'geometry'].type == 'Polygon'):
        buildings.loc[i, 'center'] = buildings.loc[i, 'geometry'].centroid
        count_buildings_poly += 1
    else:
        buildings.loc[i, 'center'] = buildings.loc[i, 'geometry']
        count_buildings_point += 1
        
print('#polygon', count_buildings_poly)
print('#point  ', count_buildings_point)

buildings['nearestnode'] = buildings['geometry']

p = buildings.loc[0, 'center'].x, buildings.loc[0, 'center'].y
p
>(7.5589873, 47.8144135)

nn_node1 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p)
nn_node1
>256970665

p2 = buildings.loc[1, 'center'].x, buildings.loc[1, 'center'].y
p2
>(7.565093, 47.814843)

nn_node2 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p2)
nn_node2
>256970665
```

Comment: `G` is earliest referenced in the test code. It should somehow have an influence on the calculation. The loop does nothing besides counting buildings. It should determine the nearest neightbor and return the distance of that. Btw. what is a "point" building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, could figure it out. I had to change lon and lat:

```
p = buildings.loc[0, 'center'].x, buildings.loc[0, 'center'].y
p
>(7.5589873, 47.8144135)

nn_node1 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p)
nn_node1
>256970665

p2 = buildings.loc[1, 'center'].x, buildings.loc[1, 'center'].y
p2
>(7.565093, 47.814843)

nn_node2 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p2)
nn_node2
>256970665
```

to:

```
p1 = [buildings.loc[0, 'center'].y, buildings.loc[0, 'center'].x]
p1
>[47.873246, 7.5688247]
nn1 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p1)
nn1
>90875045

p2 = [buildings.loc[1, 'center'].y, buildings.loc[1, 'center'].x]
p2
>[47.7893012, 7.5377884]
nn2 = ox.get_nearest_node(G, p2)
nn2
>456275
```